Regex not doing the replacement on vb.net
I need help. I am trying to get rid of some special characters on my input but it doesn't work, am I doing something wrong? Below is my code:
Dim txtFirstname as String = "ABC (A)"
Dim pat As String = "^\w\s\.\,\'\`\-\(\)"
Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex(pat)
Dim checkFname As String = rgx.Replace(txtFirstName, "")

I'm trying to achieve this output:  ABC A
but it just returns me the same input : ABC (A) not getting rid of the parentheses.

Modify the pattern as this:
Dim pat As String = "[\.\,\'\`\-\(\)]"

and the escaped special characters are replaced with " ".


Or just Dim pat As String = "[-.,'\()]"because-` has no special meaning if it is the first character in a character class, and the others have no special meaning—so they do not need to be escaped—in a character class.
